# problem of canvas S refresh Android Studio

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am trying to create a pong Game in Android Studio, but I have a problem, which I think can be solved easily, but I don't know how.

This is my code :

My Pong class

```
public class Pong extends View {
    //Attributes
        private Rect joueur1 = new Rect();
        private Rect joueur2 = new Rect();
        public Pong(Context ctx){
            super(ctx);
        }

    public void setJoueur1(Rect joueur1) {
        this.joueur1 = joueur1;
    }

    public void setJoueur2(Rect joueur2) {
        this.joueur2 = joueur2;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawRect(joueur1,p);
        canvas.drawRect(joueur2,p);

    }

}
```

My class Barre

```
public class Barre {
    private Rect hitBox = new Rect();
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private static final int width = 20; //width = longeur
    private static final int height =100;

    public Barre(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

    }
    public void setHitBox (){
        hitBox.set(x,y,width,height);
    }

    public Rect getHitBox() {
        return hitBox;
    }
}
```

My class main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Attributs

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Pong pong = new Pong(this);

        Barre joueur1 = new Barre(10,0);
        Barre joueur2  = new Barre(200,0);

        joueur1.setHitBox();
        joueur2.setHitBox();

        pong.setJoueur1(joueur1.getHitBox());
        pong.setJoueur2(joueur2.getHitBox());


        pong.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        setContentView(pong);
        
    }
}
```

the problem is that my player 2 (second barre) is not shown

Some Important details:

- I have tried to debug my app, but everything is correct. The constructor gets the information and sets it in "joueur1" and "joueur2"
- I don't have any thing in my XML code
- I don't have the last version of AS but I think the problem is not from here
- is my code clear

Comment: Could you upload your MainActivity as well?

Comment: yes , i forgot to do

Comment: Could it be that your player 2 is drawn 'out of sight'? Out of the borders of Pong?

Comment: no it is not , but i note that i have this error msg : 
**E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextClassifierHelper.getTextClassifier**